# Regex - disallow combinations like "u12345"

Tags: regex, validation, pattern-matching

I need to disallow combinations in this structure:

- start by small "u"

  - the 5 following characters can not be numbers within (if starts by "u")
- except this disallowed combination, allow only `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

I did only regex like `^[^u][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]$`, because I have no idea for add only except for starting by "u".

List of some allowed combinations:

- u12adfw3
- u1a234
- ud1235

And list of disallowed combinations:

- u12345
- u91
- u1

I need this for aliases for system-generated name like "u20". Because I am creating system, when user can be identified by name/alias/e-mail (just looking for that string in database) and because user do not must set own alias, I want get there some limits. The destination of this regex is "pattern" in input tag in HTML or PHP check after submit.

If you have some interesting tutorials to do that/topics with simiplar problem or you just want help me, thanks you in advance :)

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking that in PHP, you could use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) and check with this regex:

```
^(?!u\d{1,5}\b)
```

`preg_match` will return false if the string begins with a `u` and 1 to 5 digits.

`^` matches at the beginning of the string.

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead. If what's inside matches, the whole regex will fail.

`u\d{1,5}` is to match u followed by 1 to 5 digits.

`\b` is a word boundary and will prevent any following word characters.

Comment: May also want to add a `$` to the end of the lookahead, since apparently 'u12adfw3' and 'u1a234' should be allowed.